# Merging different user master tables in to one user master

Tags: database, postgresql

I have tree projects running in production with three different `Postgres` databases which manage their users individually and the tables are given below.

---

**Sales Panel** --> Database: salesDB, Table: user_master (id, name), other_table1,...

**Talent Panel** --> Database: talentDB, Table: employee_master (id, name), other_table2, ...

**Buyer Panel** --> Database: buyerDB, Table: buyer_master (id, name), other_table3, ...

---

> Now I want to manage all users in one new table by creating a new database for Admin Panel.

Example:
**Admin Panel** --> Database: adminDB, Tables   : user_master (id, name)

---

Question is,

> 1) If I create new user_master table then how to manage existing user's primary id which is in use?

If there is another way then please suggest me.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Please, don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh I am using **postgres**

Comment: flagged as to broad.... Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I have limited this question to the specific problem so, I am requesting to reopen this question if I am doing wrong then please guide me also.